# Sending user weight to Smart Trainer via ANT+FEC over BLE

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

Does anyone has any knowledge of how to send user weight settings to DataPage 55 for a indoor Smart Trainer?

I want update user weight such that grade simulation can be made more realistic. I have managed to get Grade (data page 51) sent successfully and implementing the same format for User Weight doesn't seem to do anything.

```
func sendUserConfig(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, characteristics: CBCharacteristic, userWeight: Double)  {
    let userWeightKG = (400)
    
    let uWeightLSB = UInt8(Int(userWeightKG) & 0xFF)
    let uWeightMSB = UInt8(Int(userWeightKG) >> 8) & 0xFF
    
    print("<><>  uWeightLSB:\(uWeightLSB) uWeightMSB:\(uWeightMSB)")
    
    var rawArray = [UInt8]()
    rawArray.insert(0xA4, at:0)   //Sync
    rawArray.insert(0x09, at:1)   //Length
    rawArray.insert(0x4F, at:2)   //Acknowledge message type
    rawArray.insert(0x05, at:3)   //Channel
    rawArray.insert(0x37, at:4)   //Page 55
    rawArray.insert(uWeightLSB, at:5)
    rawArray.insert(uWeightMSB, at:6)
    rawArray.insert(0xFF, at:7)   // reserved
    rawArray.insert(0xFF, at:8)   // Bike Wheel Diameter Offset + Bike Weight LSN
    rawArray.insert(0xFF, at:9)   // Bike Weight MSB (0xFF = default invalid)
    rawArray.insert(0xFF, at:10)  // Bike Wheel Diameter (0xFF = default invalid)
    rawArray.insert(0x00, at:11)  // Gear Ratio (0x00 = default invalid)
    rawArray.insert(0xFF, at:12)  //ChkSum
    let data = Data(rawArray)
    
   peripheral.writeValue(data, for: characteristics, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
  }
```

[image]

Framing Format for the Message
[image]

Comment: Your length is a little surprising (which bytes is it counting? ), and are you sure that the chksum is 0xff? You didn't link any docs for the framing format (whatever defines "sync" etc).

Comment: @RobNapier Added the framing format. For the checksum, yeah, it's not correct. I used the same 0xff for sending target power and target slope and it works :-p (I didn't know how to do an XOR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was missing was the unit. The user weight data expects a data with units of 0.01kg hence to send

```
40kg  =  40 / 0.01 = 4000
100kg = 100 / 0.01 = 10000
```